# Request Mapping in Spring MVC. Identical/Same function, just different mapping, fails

Tags: spring-mvc

The first Request mapping below (//1) function is called and returns a response. (Null for now, there is no data in the database.

The second Mapping bellow its (path=testnow) is exactly the same just with different mapping,  but returns a 404? Why?

```
package io.egen.rest.controller;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import io.egen.rest.entity.Movie;
    import io.egen.rest.service.MovieService;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(path = "movies")
    public class MovieController {

        @Autowired
        MovieService service;

        //1
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
        public List<Movie> findAll() {
            return service.findAll();
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "testnow", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
        public List<Movie> testUrlNow() {
            return service.findAll();
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
        public Movie findOne(@PathVariable("id") String movieId) {
            return service.findOne(movieId);
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
        public Movie create(@RequestBody Movie movie) {
            return service.create(movie);
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, path = "{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
        public Movie update(@PathVariable("id") String empId, @RequestBody Movie emp) {
            return service.update(empId, emp);
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, path = "{id}")
        public void delete(@PathVariable("id") String empId) {
            service.delete(empId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can add other files if they are needed. 

Background: it is a Java Spring MVC web application. (Uses JPA + Hibernate and MySQL) 

the service.findAll() goes on to the service and then to repository which uses hibernate to talk to MySQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKAY! You won't believe this!

Restarting Eclipse solved the problem! I can hit both urls now!

(maybe a cacheing / project clean / server clean / cached entity mapping etc Issue)

it may be an IT cliche but sometimes "turn it of and Turn it back on again" it definitely works!!

Thanks for the help though guys, really appreciate it.

And I know this is a stupid post. But maybe someone like me will benefit from it! so I am going to let this question stay up/.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the testnow endpoint like this `/movies/testnow` then then path should be changed as following.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/testnow", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public List<Movie> testUrlNow() {
    return service.findAll();
}
```

If not you have to call the testnow endpoint as `/moviestestnow`

Comment: nope doesn't work! I tried. (and I was told by a web developer that spring takes care of the "/" ... unless there are two... like "test/now{id}" 

http://localhost:8080/spring-rest/api/movies/testnow/

(Apache server, if that makes a difference)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I checked some examples from my old projects and it had

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/application")
public class ApplicationController {

...


@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET) {
....
}


}
```

Note the annotation param is "value" and not "path"..

Comment: @feltspar Are you using spring boot? Can you turn on debug logging to see if it prints a full list of URLs mapped to the servlet context when the app starts up?

Answer (score -1):

```
@Autowired
    MovieService service;

    //1
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Movie> findAll() {
        return service.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/testnow", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Movie> testUrlNow() {
        return service.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Movie findOne(@PathVariable("id") String movieId) {
        return service.findOne(movieId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Movie create(@RequestBody Movie movie) {
        return service.create(movie);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, path = "/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public Movie update(@PathVariable("id") String empId, @RequestBody Movie emp) {
        return service.update(empId, emp);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, path = "/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable("id") String empId) {
        service.delete(empId);
    }
```

try that way .

And we didn't suggest return type equal void , you can return a status type to the page , so as to make sure you  operation is success or not

Comment: `@RestController` annotation adds `@ResponseBody` to all the annotated controller methods already

Comment: @OlegKurbatov thank you for your remind , i did't pay attention to the RestController